# Equality check in VbScript

Tags: vbscript, equality

```
dim rc
dim num
rc = InputBox("Enter rc")
for i=1 to rc 
    if(i=rc) then
        WScript.echo "Equal"
    end if
next
```

The above code does not print Equal when i enter 5 in the InputBox. Is this a issue because i and rc are of different types?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
dim rc
dim i
rc = CInt(InputBox("Enter rc"))

for i= 1 to rc
    if i=rc then
        MsgBox "Equal"
    end if
next
```

Your assumption is correct. By default, InputBox returns a variant with string subtype. Hence, you need to change its type before comparison. In your case, i is of int subtype, hence I changed the return value of InputBox to int.

Comment: Note that for values outside the interval [-32768;32767] you need to use `CLng`.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination Pankaj.